# jQuery Morph Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im not sure if the title is what im trying to describe but ill have a go.

I have two classes

"big_green" and "small_blue"

big_green = 100x100 green box
small_blue = 50x50 blue box

i remember there used to be a js library that allowed you to tween classes, i think it was  mootools. Anyway, is there any way in jQuery to animate the changes between two classes. Example:

```
<div class="big_green"></div>
```

changes its class to small_blue but the transition is animated. It goes through all the sizes in between 100x100 and 50x50 and all colour values between green and blue. Sorry if the question is a bit confusing as im not really good at explaining things :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) should be exactly what you are looking for, if I understand your problem.  It's a part of the jQuery UI library.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for :) (shame its buggy in opera tho)

Comment: I'm sure those 5 Opera users will be so pissed.